# "Location is required." Exception FXML in Eclipse and maybe other IDEs

Tags: eclipse, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, fxmlloader

I want to share this little tip with you because it was a big pain in the ass for me in the beginning.

When adding a new FXMLLoader in your code that should load a new file, it doesn't work in the beginning if you've created that FXML file with an external application, like SceneBuilder for example.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to refresh your project directory or at least the folder/package where you stored your FXML file(s). Right-click -> Refresh or simple F5 (but you'll have to click the package/folder first).

Assuming that nothing else is responsibly for your Exception, now run it and it will load the new FXML file correctly.